# Is there an `at` style interface to `apscheduler`?

Tags: python-2.7, apscheduler

I have `cgi` script that sends out an email; occasionally the email server is busy and the email doesn't get sent.

As part of the `except` clause of an emailing `try` construct, I'd it to try again in, say, 10 minutes or so.  How would I schedule the `resend()` function to only fire once? Do I have to remove the job whilst in the `resend()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Scheduler.add_date_job()](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/dateschedule.html). Use something like [datetime.now()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) + [timedelta(minutes=10)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) when scheduling.

Comment: The scheduler wasn't installed in my Ubuntu 12.04 installaion of python 2.7.4; look here: http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/#installing-apscheduler